# Isotope jQuery with Slider

Tags: jquery-isotope

I am new to Isotope jQuery and I want to integrate the Isotope with a jQuery slider. How can i do this?

Comment: I can't even picture in my head what you are trying to accomplish. You should ask a better question.

Comment: Please describe exactly how you'd like the jQuery slider to interact with Isotope.

Answer (score 0):

I think gaining clarity through the question will help to answer it.

I think Shahzad wants a jquery slider element on a page.  This slider element will have values. From 0 to x.

Through using the filter element of the Isotope, he probably wants to use the Isotope effect when a user moves the slider to different values to filter certain items on the web page.

Would this be it? If it is, how would it be done, as I'm interested in this answer too. :)

Answer (score 0):

It works with class names, so it may be possible to add class names using Jquery when you set the range of the slider.

Something like this : the slider's minimum value is 3, the maximum is 8 :

- Create a hidden filter (which will be used as itemselector)
- For each element with a value from 3 to 8, add a class like 'showIt', and remove this class for the others.
- Add a data-filter "showIt" attribute on the hidden filter, and trigger.('click') on it.

It's still pure theory, and maybe I'm totally wrong. I'll try it myself (I'm working on a website with several sliders working simulatneously, cross fingers !) and post let you know if it works...